# R: Search google for a string and return number of hits

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to simply search google for something and then return the number of results? I have seen alot of R packages around some service of google (RGoogleDocs, RGoogleData, RGoogleMaps, googleVis), but I can't find this feature anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I think I recall Google has an API for that but I don't recall seeing a package.  By studying the other RGoogleFoo packages you may be able to cook something up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I use, but it's based on an API protocol that's eventually being phased out. It's also rate limited, I believe to 100 searches/day. In the below function, service is "web"; you'll need to get a key from http://code.google.com/apis/loader/signup.html (any URL will work).

```
GetGoogleResults <- function(keyword, service, key) {       
  library(RCurl)
  library(rjson)
  base_url <- "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/"
  keyword <- gsub(" ", "+", keyword)
  query <- paste(base_url, service, "?v=1.0&q=", keyword, sep="")
  if(!is.null(key))
    query <- paste(query, "&key=", key, sep="")

  query <- paste(query, "&start=", 0, sep="")
  results <- fromJSON(getURL(query))
  return(results)
}
```

Then, you can do something like

```
google <- GetGoogleResults("searchTerm", "web", yourkey)
```

`str(google)` will tell you the structure of the result. If you just want the number of results, you can use `google$responseData$cursor$estimatedResultCount`.

As I said, this  is based on a protocol that may go out of style some day. Per Dirk's answer, there is an alternate approach using a custom search engine that you can use instead, but it's also rate limited (if you want a function for this method, you can ping me at noah_at_noahhl.com).

The final, and not rate limited,  way is just to use RCurl to get a page from google, but it's pretty messy to parse, and requires spoofing a user agent to get around Google's attempts to prevent people from doing this. (I can also share this code, but it gets broken whenever Google tweaks any of their HTML).

Comment: I'll just add - this is a problem I've run into a few times. If there's sufficient interest, I'll package up all the bits and pieces I have and make it a real package.

Comment: Awesome! I had to enter an `else` between the two query assignments but other than that this does exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Good catch, my bad - I took this piece out of a bigger function that paginates through results to get more results. Rather than coding an"else", just replace <code>startpos</code> with a zero.

Comment: I've been trying my hands on basic screen scraping for google search results, and this was what i was attempting to do. Tried to do I've ran your script, but the estimated search results from your function do not match up with the estimated search results obtained from manually running a search through a web browser as an example, i've searched for my name Your function: received 13,800 responses Manually: About 3,860,000 results (0.08 seconds) Is there a reason why?

Comment: @Noah Did you have get around to packaging the bits and pieces into an R package? Very interesting function btw!

Comment: @Noah, would also be super interested if this became a real package.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start at the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) documentation and then see how much JSON you have to learn to hit it :)

There should be enough R infrastructure in place to get something going.